# Using Drupal Commerce as a Quote Form

Tags: commerce

I have a client who needs to allow customers to put products in a cart so that they can be custom quoted, instead of purchased online. Is Drupal Commerce aptly suited for this? If so, what are some strategies to hide pricing throughout the process?

Comment: How much else of the process can make use of Commerce? What you describe sounds much more like a webform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Drupal Commerce fits this need perfectly as you can pretty much disable the entire notion of payments etc. no problem and the rest of the system won't mind at all.

The default "add to cart form" you use for adding stuff to your cart doesn't even display price.

Also, making a view out of the current user's shopping cart order (shopping cart contents are for Drupal Commerce "orders", just incomplete ones) to make a custom display of what the user has compiled and to make a rule for checkout that just sends the "order" to you(r) client.

I'd be happy to answer any more detailed questions you might run into, but in general, the answer is "yes" as the architecture of Drupal Commerce is very flexible and as it's fully entity-based, it integrates seamlessly with all other aspects of your Drupal site.